# MYSQL JOIN - range

Tags: mysql

I have two tables Table A (below)

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| group     | age_start | age_end | 
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 01        | 01        | 04      | 
| 02        | 05        | 07      | 
| 03        | 08        | 11      | 
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

and Table B containing complete information profile of users. Table B has a column of age which contains age (2digits). Created another column in Table B called group. I want to be able to update Table B group column using the age column based on Table A age_start and age_end. Can I please request much appreciated help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Use and `update` with `join`:

```
update b join
       a
       on b.age between age_start and age_end
    set b.`group` = a.`group`;
```

By the way, `group` is a bad name for a column, because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks Gordon appreciate your quick response and pointer to the "group" name. My bad on that as it is in the table called age_group. However, I am sure it will help many new learners like myself.  Solution worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE query can be used using JOINS as following:

```
UPDATE tableB b SET b.group = a.group 
INNER JOIN tableA a ON b.age BETWEEN a.age_start AND a.age_end;
```

Comment: Many Thanks Parkash. Grateful for your help and time.